# Ttrying ubuntu 12.04 64 bit from a usb stick

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, 64-bit

I've only been using Ubuntu for a couple of weeks (ex Windows (pun intended)) and I've broken and reinstalled it 5 times. It's a new asrock board with AMD A4-5300 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2.

Every time I install the graphics driver Ubuntu brakes (black screen with a momentary "Signal out of range" message or black and white strips) and I find myself in recovery mode and very quickly learning how to use the console.  I've removed fglrx twice and got it running again but other times I just reloaded and started from scratch...

I've read just about every post here on installing this driver and tried some and came to the conclusion that there is no driver for this thing, stuck with 1024 x 768. I cant continue playing with the setup, I've got to reload programs and do some work.

So, then I thought maybe it's a 64 bit driver and I'm trying to install it in a 32 bit version of Ubuntu... any thoughts on that?  I have noticed quite a few with the same or similar problems and not to many [SOLVED]...

But now my question, If I try and install the driver whilst running from a usb stick using the 64 bit version in trial mode, will there be any chance of 1, breaking the HD installation and 2, any chance of it working... Or alternatively, can I throw a video card in and ignore the on-board goodies? I'm not a gamer...  Your thoughts?

Comment: if your machine is capable of 64 bit, then I'd recommend always installing a 64-bit operating system.

Answer (score 0):

"`signal out of range`" means that the driver you're trying to use (fglrx) is trying to display a resolution not supported by your monitor. If you read the documentation on fglrx I'm sure there is a command line method of changing the driver's default resolution.

If you are not running games or high graphics-intensive programs, can you not just use the default linux Nouveau driver instead of installing proprietary video card drivers? If it is a new card then it may not have linux support for the proprietary driver yet.

Also yes if you're trying to install software on a 32bit operating system or machine, it will not work. If your machine is 64bit why can you not just boot from 64bit live-CD, and reinstall, replacing the 32bit version of Ubuntu?

If you boot from 64bit live-CD and use that to try to install software on a 32bit already installed system, and it actually allows you to do so in the first place, when you reboot to HD it will break almost guaranteed. Which again begs the question, why can you not just use a 64bit system on your machine?

Comment: OK, thank you to theferrit32 for your input, I took your advice and installed the 64-bit system, searched and found the Nouveau driver is only for Nvidia graphics so I found and installed the Radeon driver, documentation is little short on that. When I re-booted, Ubuntu was again broken... I had no pile of paper in front of me explaining how to remove or adjust the driver so I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit version again. I don't believe there is a driver that supports this hardware.  So can you or anyone else recommend a solid video card that is good for desktop use that is well supported?

Comment: First I would recommend to you to install Ubuntu 64bit v 13.10. While 12.04 is LTS and _**should**_ work, the kernel and Ubuntu software and repos will not get major updates past April 2012. There are significant improvements that have been made between then and October 2013 (13.10) including new drivers with much better linux support. Secondly the Ubuntu Ubiquity installer runs a tool to determine the best open-source driver available for your system and installs it for you. If you do a fresh install and your monitor works with the driver Ubiquity gave you there is no reason to modify it

Comment: Since Apr 4 and advice taken from theferrit32, I have re-loaded several times, killed it in every variety I could find...  Came to the conclusion that the graphics chip on my new board is faulty, I purchased a PCI card, installed it and the recommended drivers. Working fine and have a resolution I can live with. After looking at what was available I settled on Kubuntu 13.10  64 bit. Thank you all for your interest and help.